# EditText doesn't fill the whole height of the window

Tags: android, android-edittext

EditText doesn't fill the whole height of the window. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

            <Button android:id="@+id/bItalic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ></Button>

            <Button android:id="@+id/bBold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <Button android:id="@+id/bUnderline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <Button android:id="@+id/bStrike"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="S"
                />

            <Button android:id="@+id/bSub"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <Button android:id="@+id/bSup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/bInsertImage"
                android:src="@drawable/insertimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/bInsertTable"
                android:src="@drawable/table"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/FrameLayout02"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            >

            <TabHost android:id="@+id/tabhost"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />
                <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:paddingTop="62px">

                    <ScrollView 
                        android:id="@+id/scroll01" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                        <HorizontalScrollView 
                            android:id="@+id/scroll_hor01" 
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                                <EditText 
                                    android:id="@+id/VisualPane" 
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                 />
                        </HorizontalScrollView>
                    </ScrollView>

                    <ScrollView 
                        android:id="@+id/scroll02" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                        <HorizontalScrollView 
                            android:id="@+id/scroll_hor02" 
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                                <EditText 
                                    android:id="@+id/HTMLPane" 
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />  
                        </HorizontalScrollView>
                    </ScrollView>   
                </FrameLayout>
            </TabHost>
        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image: http://s48.radikal.ru/i122/1101/a4/030018887e7b.jpg]

Why doesn't EditText fill the whole height of the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent **LinearLayout** property

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

must be

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

You can set the following property of the `EditText` view

```
android:layout_margin="1dip"
```

This is a bit of a hack but will work for now.

Comment: besides, editText doesn't fill the whole width of the window too

Comment: Set following property of the EditText android:layout_margin="1dip"

Answer (score 3):

The width of HorizontalScrollView is the maximum width of its elements, so you can't use fill parent inside there, because the parent's width is undefined, hence it will be 0. What you are looking for - i think - is the android:scrollHorizontally attribute of EditText. Vertically it's scrollable by default (if it's size exceeds the display), so you shouldn't place it inside any ScrollViews. Simply use an EditText with fill parent dimensions, and with scrollHorizontally="true". Also make sure that the LinearLayout containing it also has fill parent height.

Answer (score -1):

Setting following properties helped me to change the size:
android:minHeight="105px"
android:layout_height="115px"
android:layout_width="250px"

Comment: :) I agree! My app required that. My point is about the EditText properties: minHeight, layout_height, layout_width.  
One can always use the API calls to set values for those properties dynamically!

Comment: Hope you set the values by verifying the current height and widths of view, the phone orientation, etc. You can use properties like, layout_marginLeft, similarly Right, Top, Bottom, to set appropriate margins.

Comment: I tried your exact layout (without drawables), and it handles like your uploaded image. I tried and set different background colors of every component and noticed that Scroll Views does not fill the entire parent. Also ScrollView is subclass of FrameLayout, I don't see purpose of embeding several Layouts one in another.